# how to parse multiple values with same object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython

I want to parse the vaule of user from json response and send email to those id`s using python2.7

I can send it to one user, but not sure how to embed multiple users

```
role = {
    "permissions": [],
    "principals": [
        {
            "username": "EP@google.com",
            "fullname": "null"
        },
        {
            "username": "pE@google.com",
            "fullname": "null"
        }
    ]
}

role = json.loads(role)
for item in role['principals']:
    p = item['username']
    print(p)
```

It is printing as below:

```
EP@google.com
pE@google.com
```

Expected output:

```
['EP@google.com','pE@google.com']
```

Comment: So what you are printing is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
p = [item['username'] for item in role['principals']]
print(p)
```

Safe variant (won't raise error if key doesn't exist):

```
result = []
for item in role.get('principals', []):
    p = item.get('username', None)
    if p:
        result.append(p)
print(result)
```

Safe list comprehension:

```
result = [item['username'] for item in role.get('principals', []) if 'username' in item]
```